# Javascript event when cursor leaves window

Tags: javascript

im looking to create a popup which appears once on my homepage when the cursor leaves the browser as if the user was about to click back/close etc, I have the following working fine (as in the popup display) but now I need to somehow drop a cookie so it only happens once, Does anybody know or can tell me how to achieve this? Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
    }
}
addEvent(window,"load",function(e) {
    addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
        e = e ? e : window.event;
        var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
        if (!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") {
            alert("left window");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your title is very misleading.

Comment: Google "javascript cookies" turns up plenty of resources.

Comment: How come? I want an event to trigger when the cursor leaves the window?

Comment: If a user "clicks" back or close via the keyboard they won't see your popup. Maybe you should consider `onbeforeunload` or something. (Though as a user I find this sort of functionality annoying and don't recommend it at all.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.cookie` to set and get cookies.

[Here is a tutorial on js cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode:

```
ON EVENT WINDOW_MOUSEOUT
    IF event_cookie.is_present && event_cookie == EVENT_MOUSEOUT THEN
        BREAK
    ELSE
        add_cookie(EVENT_MOUSEOUT)
        do_whatever_you_need_to_do_on_first_event()
    END IF
END EVENT
```